# How MSBuild multitargeting works

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, continuous-integration, msbuild-4.0, multitargeting

I will try to explain this as clear as I can

I want to fully understand how MSBuild multitargeting works.

I have read several articles from Microsoft and I think I understand the basic but I want to be sure I am not missing anything.

According to Microsoft:

> By using Visual Studio, you can compile an application to run on any one of several versions of the .NET Framework. For example, you can compile an application to run on the .NET Framework version 2.0, and compile the same application to run on the .NET Framework version 4. The ability to compile to more than one framework is named multitargeting.
>
> Visual Studio runs under the most current version of the .NET Framework that is installed on the development computer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395432.aspx

So do this mean that Visual Studio always calls MSBuild from the latest framework installed? assuming Visual Studio 2010 is installed, it will always call: `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe` when building **any project targettting any .Net Framework version** right???

If yes, then the ability to target old .Net Framewrok versions is based on the `ToolsVersion` and/or `TargetFrameworkVersion` properties right???

**If yes again**, it would mean that just installing the latest framework (and also the older frameworks but not installing visual studio) in my Continuous Integration box, **I could point to build always any solution to: `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe` and just specify the `ToolsVersion` argument** (if required, since each project can have its own target version specified in the `TargetFrameworkVersion` which it would cause to target an older .Net Framework version).

**Following this I think my CI box would be building like Visual Studio does. Am I right? What am I missing? Is there a way to be completely sure?**

I did a quick test, and *I think it works :p* the projects are being built according to the .Net Framework specified but like I said I want to be sure I am not missing anything.

Any thoughts?

BTW:

The simple reason to want to do that is because I have several custom MSBuild scripts that are reusable accross projects, but some of the functionality in these scripts require MSBuild 4.0 and also I have several MSBuild tasks built on top of the framework 4.0 so if I have for example a solution targetting the Framework 2.0 and I try to build it using: `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MsBuild.exe` I get MSBuild errors trying to load my custom targets

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you've got it mostly correct. Calling MSBuild from the 4.0 directory will do the correct thing against previous versions. They only thing I wanted to add was that 3.5 must be on the box to actually build projects targeting 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5.

This page here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx calls out the what versions Windows comes with what version of the framework pre-installed.